# Canopy Network access on company network

Tags: python, networking, enthought

I just started using python/canopy today and I am having trouble logging in from the welcome page after installing Canopy on my company machine. On the welcome page it says I have no internet connection. I think it's due to the company firewall or other network restriction. I wonder whether there is any way around this. The error I got from the Preference->Network-> Detailed Network Access Test is below. I am using win7 and Canopy version 1.5.2.2785:

```
Method: urllib2
    Checking http://www.enthought.com/
    Failed
        URLError(gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed'),)
        {'reason': gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')}

    Checking https://www.enthought.com/
    Failed
        URLError(gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed'),)
        {'reason': gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')}

    Checking https://api.enthought.com/
    Failed
        URLError(gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed'),)
        {'reason': gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')}

    Checking https://grits.enthought.com/
    Failed
        URLError(gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed'),)
        {'reason': gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')}

    Checking https://training.enthought.com/
    Failed
        URLError(gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed'),)
        {'reason': gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')}

    Checking https://storage-cf.enthought.com/www/canopy/etod-has-access.png
    Failed
    Expected failure: ssl in python <= 2.7.8 does not support TLS SNI extension
        URLError(gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed'),)
        {'reason': gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')}

Method: requests
    Checking http://www.enthought.com/
    Failed
        ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')),)
        {'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}

    Checking https://www.enthought.com/
    Failed
        ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')),)
        {'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}

    Checking https://api.enthought.com/
    Failed
        ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')),)
        {'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}

    Checking https://grits.enthought.com/
    Failed
        ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')),)
        {'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}

    Checking https://training.enthought.com/
    Failed
        ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')),)
        {'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}

    Checking https://storage-cf.enthought.com/www/canopy/etod-has-access.png
    Failed
        ConnectionError(ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11004, 'getaddrinfo failed')),)
        {'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}

Method: qt
    Checking http://www.enthought.com/
    Failed
        PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError.HostNotFoundError
        Host www.enthought.com not found

    Checking https://www.enthought.com/
    Failed
        PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError.HostNotFoundError
        Host  not found

    Checking https://api.enthought.com/
    Failed
        PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError.HostNotFoundError
        Host  not found

    Checking https://grits.enthought.com/
    Failed
        PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError.HostNotFoundError
        Host  not found

    Checking https://training.enthought.com/
    Failed
        PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError.HostNotFoundError
        Host  not found

    Checking https://storage-cf.enthought.com/www/canopy/etod-has-access.png
    Failed
    Expected failure: ssl linked with Qt does not support TLS SNI extension
        PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NetworkError.HostNotFoundError
        Host  not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked with your IT about entering proxy firewall credentials? See https://support.enthought.com/entries/23590213-Can-I-use-Canopy-Behind-a-Proxy-Firewall-

Comment: I have local admin right on my machine and I followed the instructions at https://support.enthought.com/entries/26491185-Understanding-a-Canopy-system-wide-installation-common-install-  Any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Those are completely different and unrelated issues. Common install is about where on your disk or network the program is installed. Proxy setup is about the program (already installed) being able to get through your corporate firewall. Whether proxy is required is completely unrelated to whether you did a common install. Again, I suggest that you talk with your IT department.